# OpenGL glDrawElements with variable number of indices

Tags: c++, opengl

I've been using `glDrawElements` to draw triangles that describe objects. However, I'm trying to load some OFF objects I found online and I saw this describing the indices of the vertices:

```
...
4 195 209 210 196
4 196 210 211 197
3 197 211 15
3 0 212 198
4 198 212 213 199
4 199 213 214 200
...
```

My question is, how do I switch between drawing elements described by 3 indices of vertices and 4 (and any other number of indices). Currently I can only load in OFF files that use 3 indices to describe the vertices:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, IBO);
int size; glGetBufferParameteriv(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_BUFFER_SIZE, &size);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, size/sizeof(GLushort), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

Any tips or references/pointers to tutorials or anything related to help me generalize things?

Comment: That's what the primitive type parameter is for... but I have no idea what the lists of 4 elements are supposed to be - they could be quads, triangle strips/fans, lines, points, ...

Comment: You could possibly use `glGetBufferSubData` to read the following sequence of N vertices to draw within the IBO, and iteratively call `glDrawElements`. This would probably be inefficient...

Comment: assume they're n-gons. triangulate.

Comment: @jozxyqk could you provide a link to that technique? I kind of understand what you mean but a concrete example would be great.

Comment: @phileaton see this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation. Found an example at the bottom of [this page](http://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-advanced-lessons/obj-file-format/reading-an-obj-file/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the polygons are convex, triangulating them is easy. One approach is that you split each polygon into triangles, and then draw with primitive type `GL_TRIANGLES`. For a polygon with `n` vertices, you will end up with `n - 2` triangles defined by the vertices with the following 0-based indices:

```
0 1 2
0 2 3
0 3 4
...
0 n-2 n-1
```

For your example, the sequence of indices would be:

```
195 209 210 195 210 196
196 210 211 196 211 197
197 211 15
0 212 198
198 212 213 198 213 199
199 213 214 199 214 200
```

The more elegant approach is to draw each polygon with primitive type `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN`. The order of vertices for a triangle fan is exactly the same as for a polygon, so you can simply specify the indices in order:

```
0 1 2 3 ... n-1
```

To separate the polygons, you can use primitive restart. Enable it with:

```
glPrimitiveRestartIndex(0xffff);
glEnable(GL_PRIMITIVE_RESTART);
```

and then insert the restart index between polygons. For your example:

```
195 209 210 196 0xffff
196 210 211 197 0xffff
197 211 15 0xffff
0 212 198 0xffff
198 212 213 199 0xffff
199 213 214 200
```

Answer (score 0):

The first entry of your dataset is a quad, which can be split into 2 triangles using vertices {1,2,3} and {1,3,4} (ie {195,209,210} and {195,210,196} for the first entry). Use the same scheme for each quad you have in your dataset. If you get inverted tris, try flipping the order of the vertices ({195,210,209} instead of {195,209,210} for instance).